# Recreate Square deposit report via API

Tags: square-connect

I would like to generate a Square deposit report via the API so I can import it as an invoice into Quickbooks desktop.  I have tried `ListTransactions` and `Settlements` but each is missing some items.

What I'd like to see:

- Gross Sales
- Returns
- Discounts
- Tax collected
- Tips collected
- Gift card sales
- Fees
- Square capital payments

How do I pull all these together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried out V1 `ListPayments`? It will return itemization, total money, tax, discounts, tips, card brand (which should show you if it's a gift card), refunds, and Square fees. Regarding Square capital payments, I believe you'll still need to utilize `ListSettlements`, as `ListPayments` focuses on payments made by your customers only.

Reference: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#get-payments

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like this will do everything except the capital payments, which I don't have to deal with right now.